# Load file into QwebView

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, qwebview

I need to create function to create advertisement here: http://www.motosale.com.ua/?add=zap
In this adv. should be image. 
I have decided to create QWebView and insert each field by javascript. But i can't insert file.
How can i do that?

```
self.webView.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('model_zap')[0].value='57'")
```

I did inserting values to inputs in that way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to try with `QGraphicsWebView()` instead of `QwebView()` ?